# What is the purpose of the functions/lib folder in a Firebase project

Tags: firebase

When I use the Firebase CLI to initialise a `functions` folder in a Firebase project and then deploy the project, a `lib` folder appears within `functions`. What is the purpose of the `lib` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's your compiled code.**

Functions to run code use their version of code/language so compiler compile code to a lib folder and compiling code on your computer can throw an error if something is wrong so it prevents from some code failures on server side.

Comment: In my case, the libs folder contained the .js Javascript file resulting from the compilation of my .ts Typescript source.

Comment: If you use plain js it will compile code too. Compiling is to check are code is ok it might add some thing to code if it's necessary and if code will be sended to users it removes unnecessary coments and spaces enters etc. to lower file size.